# How to self join an entity to create a group of them with JPA?

Tags: database, jpa, join

I have this entity `product` which I want to join to itself to create a group and have access to other members of the group, when I have any of the members and a product can be only in one group or none at all,  tried to test this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;
@Column
private Long groupId;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "groupId")
private List<Product> group;
```

- I can write another entity named `group` and join using that, but is that the best way since that `group` will only bear an ID, I'm looking for the Best-Practice here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done in JPA as JPA restricts foreign keys to reference ID fields, while you want the groupId to specify something else unique among the group.  You might make the group transient, and instead lazy fetch it from the entitymanager with a query:

```
@Transient
private List<Product> group;

public List<Product> getGroup(EntityManager em) {
  if (group==null) {
    group = em.createQuery("Select p from Product p where p.groupId = :groupId").setParameter("groupId", this.getGroupId()).getResultList();
  }
  return group;
}
```